# Linking containers based on pod names in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I tried to make different pods each of them runs its own container, I tried to follow the same instructions of linking two docker containers:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name db postgres:10
```

The other container:

```
docker run -p port:port --name image-name --link db:db -t image
```

### and the Kubernetes deployments:

### DB

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
          env:
          - name: "POSTGRES_DB"
            value: "postgres"
          - name: "POSTGRES_USERNAME"
            value: "name"
          - name: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
            value: "pass"
```

### APP

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: APP
  labels:
    app: APP
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: APP
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: APP
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: APP
          image: image
          ports:
          - containerPort: port
```

Now the question, do I need to create containers in the same pod and name it in a similar name to the docker command(db=db)?
or do I need to configure the network correctly so containers can find the hostname?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a service which points to your pod (deployment). Via service, you can manage traffic across deployments.

For more info you can check this document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

if you are looking for internal dns communication

please check : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service over the database. The kubernetes docs explain the various options for doing this. Once you have a service, your pod will be able to look up that service by name using the DNS provided by kubernetes to the pod. The service acts as a proxy to the (in this case, database) pod.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, a pod is considered as the smallest unit so it makes more sense to place them in a separate pod so they have their own lifecycle. The way you are doing is definitely correct; to make them work you need to expose the DB so your App can connect to it i.e. to expose DB it as a Service of type ClusterIP and then you can reach it via its service name inside your cluster.

A simple example -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "postgres"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      protocol: TCP
      name: dbport
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgres
```

Comment: I would say that a pod is not the smallest unit, as a pod is made up of possibly >1 containers. Sorry if this is pedantic, but there could be an argument for running db and app in same pod but separate containers (it would go against the generally accepted advice, but is possible), in which case no link would be needed at all.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/